# Does Epic Typhon stops dropping legendaries past a certain level?

Tags: titan-quest

I started farming Typhon on Epic and was wondering if he stops dropping legendary items if my character is past a certain level. I'm 51 at the moment and after hours of farming over a week, I havent seen a single legendary drop.

Some say to just move on to epic for more chances on drops, but bah!, if epic Typhon does drop legendaries I'll keep at it a bit. I want Persephone's Caress bad before going into Legendary mode.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the best place to farm for Persephone's Caress was the cyclops on legendary as he uses clubs.  I remember finding a bunch from him while trying to get another weapon.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I played Titan Quest, and I can't remember how far I got into redoing the later difficulty levels, but if the bosses follow the same rules as the normal monsters in the game, if a monster isn't dropping items it's not because you're too high of a level, it's because that monster isn't strong enough to have a % chance to drop what you're looking for.

ie- a max level character will have the same drop chances from normal level bosses as a character of appropriate level.